# Apache mod_rewrite to return a 404 except one directory

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-404, rewrite, rewritecond

I'm trying to configure Apache to return a default 404 page when the / of DocumentRoot is called, except for some directories in that DocumentRoot

Unfortunately, I'm getting a 404 even for the directories that have been specified in the RewriteCond directive.

Here is my setup :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !/dir1/
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !/dir2/
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: nm, got it working with

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/dir1(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/dir2(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]

Comment: In the future, this might be of use: http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2007/09/05/a-couple-ways-to-debug-mod_rewrite

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Convert [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/293792/apache-mod-rewrite-to-return-a-404-except-one-directory#comment277842_293792) to CW</sub>

I got it working with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/dir1(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/dir2(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```